# HttpUrlConnection POST not working as expected

Tags: java

I'm new to writing network code, and not very familiar with Java programming.

I'm trying to write a snippet to log into a website. I need to use http POST to submit the username and password.

I wrote a version using Apache http components and it worked fine, I could see there was a HTTP POST when monitoring the connection using Wireshark.

```
StringEntity loginForm = new StringEntity(postData);
HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost(LOG_IN_URL);
loginPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
loginPost.setEntity(loginForm);
client.execute(loginPost);
```

*The version above worked.*

The `postData` is

```
private static String getPostData(String checkCode) {
    String postinfo1 = "operation=&usercode_text=myusername&userpwd_text=password&checkcode_text=";
    String postinfo2 = "&submittype=%C8%B7+%C8%CF";
    String postData = postinfo1 + checkCode + postinfo2;
    return postData;
}
```

Then I wrote another one using HttpUrlConnection

```
URL logInUrl = new URL(LOG_IN_URL);
HttpURLConnection logConn = (HttpURLConnection) logInUrl.openConnection();
logConn.setDoOutput(true);
logConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
logConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
logConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
OutputStream out = logConn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter logPost = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
logPost.print(postData);
logPost.close();
```

After this block is executed, I can only see some TCP packages on Wireshark, but not a HTTP POST after them (as in the case with the Apache http components version), and I cannot log in to the website.

*I am curious about the possible difference in the two versions of code the cause the latter to fail.*

**UPDATE**
I don't know why. But after I added

```
logConn.getResponseCode();
```

It works now. (Deleting this line it will fail). Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Is the URL you are trying to access secure?  If so, then you would need to access it via HTTPS using `HttpsURLConnection`.  Can you share the url with us?

Comment: @Tim Nope, it's not using HTTPS. I will post the Apache http client code which worked.

Comment: How could you possibly be logging in when you never pass any credentials to the site?  And I believe that a request is going out, perhaps you are reading Wireshark wrongly.

Comment: what is your `postData`?

Comment: @Tim It's my school's website. I don't know the detail, but in the postData, I put the username, encrypted password and a validate code (to ensure I'm not a robot), then the website gives back a JSESSIONID cookie, with which I can access my class schedule, etc.

Comment: The wombat noticed that you don't appear to be ever setting any post data in your Java code.  Can you include this code if you actually even have it?

Comment: One last question: What is your current output from the POST call?  Is there any error message present?

Comment: @Tim I think I got a 200, and then redirected to the "log in" page again when I try to access other parts of the website. In the version that worked, I could then go on to access my schedule in the website with the cookie.

Comment: If you're getting a 200, then this implies the call succeeded.  I'm not even convinced you have a problem right now.  Just take the access token and get on with the rest of your project.

Comment: Don't use `PrintWriter` over the network. It swallows exceptions you need to know about. Use `BufferedWriter.write()`.

Comment: @Tim But I cannot access other parts of the website, which means that I haven't successfully logged in. I will check the response code, just to be sure. My school's website is not a well-written one though!

Comment: @EJP Could you give some more detail? I'm really new to this :)

Comment: Please investigate the response you are getting back, as it seems you are getting something back.  And pay heed to the comment by @EJP.

Comment: @Tim It's a 200. This is weird.

Comment: No, it's not weird at all.  The `200` response just means that the HTTP call completed end-to-end without a network failure, drop, etc.  The response body itself you got back can be chock full of errors.  Please investigate this before making more comments.

Comment: @Tim I tried to use wrong username in the Apache http client version before, and the response is always 200 with empty body. The difference was only that I got redirected to log in page when trying to access other pages.

Comment: This is my last comment: Try using SOAP UI as a sanity check to make sure you have the right credentials.  Then check the contents of that `200` response and get your house in order.